# How to prevent user from entering spaces in an input form field in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, dom-events

I have created a component called **QueryForm** to be used for search functionality. I am returning in that component this:

Comment: the simplest way would be to not update them into your state: `setInputValue(newValue.replace(" ", ""));`

Comment: That's just brilliant. But it will be good if I can prevent key events, like in some examples it mentioned event.which === 32, but it didn't work.... Any work around that?

Comment: @BrattyNeal Is there a specific reason why you want to do it this way? This sure prevents users from typing spaces, but they can still be able to copy-paste spaces or using the keyboard on smartphones to do that.

Comment: you're adding more complexity to your app, what is the specific requirement? If you really want to do that you would need to refactor your code, and use the keydown event handler, instead of the onchange,  validate the keycode against a list of keys to ignore, and choose to update state or not.....

Comment: oh by smartphones!!! didnt think that deep. I think this will do fine

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can replace the spaces to empty string while setting the value:

```js
const onChange = (event, { newValue }) => {
  setInputValue(newValue.replace(/\s/g, ''));
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Good answers, but they are all assuming the input is controlled. For uncontrolled forms you want to make sure the validation is made before the onChange event is triggered. A solution that works for controlled and uncontrolled forms is this:

```
const onKeyDown = (event) => {
  if (event.code === 'Space') event.preventDefault()
}
```

Below with types included

```
const onKeyDown = (event: KeyboardEvent): void => {
  if (event.code === 'Space') event.preventDefault()
}
```

If there are more needs other than reject blank spaces the condition of that "if" statement could be a regex expression or a refactorized function.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use `trim`

```
export default function App() {
  const [val, setVal] = useState();

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <input
        value={val}
        onChange={(e) => {
          setVal(e.target.value.trim());
        }}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

[**Codesandbox**](https://codesandbox.io/s/bold-shamir-vfqde?file=/src/App.js:58-303)

Comment: `trim()` only removes spaces at prefix and suffix; you can add a space between characters. So this does not completely answer the question.

Comment: Trim doesn't solve the case where the user copies and paste a string "foo bar", for example